# powerpoint record rehearsal timings

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, powerpoint

Does anyone know how to set powerpoint's record slideshow/rehearsal timings using c# or VB? Can it be done in the open xml files? Or what developer references am I overlooking? I want to be able to choose a different method for timing up a self running presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code to add a 2 1/2 second rehearsal Timing to Powerpoint

```
slide.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime =2.5f;
slide.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceOnTime = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Took me forever to find this, so hoping it helps others
Happy Programming!

Answer (score 1):

AdvanceTime is stores the duration of the whole slide the event trigger time is stored in tag.xml file as Timing the values are stored as a pipe delimiter values like '|34.0|34|3|5.4'